# Can not Resolved FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials()

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to achieve Firebase authentication using `customToken`.

Getting error while doing below:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                         .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("path to file") //different in actual
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

It says can not resolve `setCredentials()` and after this when I'm trying to creat token is gives same error:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);
```

Searched all over the net cant find solution please help

Dependencies used are as below:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
```

Comment: Add the gradle depedency you are using for firebase.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: I mean add the depedency with the question .

Comment: Just add all in question of firebase .

Comment: Why are you using `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+`?  That's extremely old.

Comment: what i the latest version available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perfect answer to question is to add below dependency to your app level graddle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.2.0'
```

all the issues will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change your dependecies with:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

And also please don't forget to add:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

In your `build.gradle` file (Project).

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more informations.

Please also remove:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
```

Because is not needed anymore, `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1"` will do the jos as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_database_code).

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.1

Comment: changed to com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1 gradle synced successfully, but the main essue remains same.

Comment: Sorry my mistake should be `com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1` and not `15.0.1`. Please also remove `implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'` as in my updated anwer, does it work now?

Comment: I have gone throught FirebaseOptions.Builder() there is no such method called setCredentials()

Comment: Then you can use `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`, right?

Comment: What is happening now?

Comment: can not resolve setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))

Comment: This is basically another problem. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.