# Is base64 a good option for encoding custom Document IDS for Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on creating some users in my firebase app and I would like to provide custom user ids as they are authenticating with an external service.

For example my user ID generation is consisted by 2 parts like so:

```
AuthService:AuthServiceUsername
```

That can look in reality like:

```
Instragram:dimitrioskanellopoulos
```

But I dont like to have this string used as a user id so I encode it to base64 like so:

```
  const uid = Buffer.from(`instagram:${serviceUserID}`).toString('base64');
```

Is there any risk for me doing that ? Is base64 ok to be used also in regards to query params?

Comment: Base64 is kind of basic encoding that anyone can understand, What i do is use node bcrypt or use multi base64 Encoding base64 2-3 times

Comment: "But I don't like to have this string used as a user id" Why not?

Comment: The Firebase Authentication UID is **not** a secret, but merely an identifier. It is explicitly meant to be used to identify that user. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220681/can-i-login-into-a-users-account-if-i-just-know-uid-in-firebase

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I do understand that but I would like to avoid a string from a service that could be not compatible with the UID that firestore accepts. Its an edge case but that is dependant then to the service I authenticate against and that is not on my hands.

Comment: Firestore document IDs are quite flexible on what's allowed and not. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits. But base64 would actually not be safe, since it contains `/`, which is disallowed in Firestore document IDs.

Comment: Actually that is what I was looking for

Comment: Any suggested way todo this ?

Comment: @Sohan do you use this for firebase IDS?

Comment: I have not used this,but unless firebase store is fine with it this should work

Comment: @Jimmy Also I did some search, it is okay even if we do not encode userId because one can login only with credentials using flogin form

Comment: @Sohan but Frank said that that trailing slash that base64 creates sometimes is not legal for IDS

Comment: @Jimmy That is what i said in my earlier comment, do you really need encoding?

Comment: @Sohan yes because I cannot trust the service uid that provides

Comment: @Jimmy How about using hashing ?

Comment: @Sohan lets follow up here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289120/how-to-create-a-firestore-safe-document-id 
Opened a new question that describes better my problem

Comment: @JimmyKane like what Sohan asked, why not use hash e.g. SHA256?

Comment: @choopage-JekBao CPU costy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore document IDs are quite flexible on what's allowed and not. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits.

But base64 would actually not be safe, since it contains `/`, which is disallowed in Firestore document IDs

Comment: Thank you I deleted my answer as it was just your words :-)