# Why shouldnt you authenticate with the user UID when using firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the firebase documentation for managing users, it says:

```
// The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
// this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
// you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
```

I am currently using the user's UID to get certain pieces of data from my backend. Should I not be doing this? Can someone explain what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I think it's saying you shouldn't log in a user using only the UUID. It's better practice to use getToken() instead since it's unique to each request and can't be duplicated. This only applies when authenticating via a backend server.

Comment: That's indeed the reason @hudson. Can you write it up in an answer, so I can upvote it? .   And for wnba_youngboy: also see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221760/firebase-is-auth-uid-a-shared-secret and  and Doug's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53220681/can-i-login-into-a-users-account-if-i-just-know-uid-in-firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's saying you shouldn't log in a user using only the UUID. It's better practice to use `getToken()` instead since it's unique to each request and can't be duplicated. This only applies when authenticating via a backend server.